# No 'encodings' module error with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

After running a python script (With python 3.6 (64 bit) I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000034c (most recent call first):
```

I looked around and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings). Running the .exe file as an administrator and removing the ENV variables however did not solve my problem. Any thoughts on where I should look next?

Comment: Did you rerun the Python setup as an administrator or did you rerun python.exe as an administrator?

Comment: In Windows, you **need** the Python environment variables...