# Issue with Python Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have been using Jupyter notebook to create a classifier with keras and as advised, i had to uninstall newer versions of python and install python 3.6.1 which is the last version compatible with keras as of now. After reinstalling python, when i try to open jupyter notebook it crashes or when i type python in cmd it gives me the error :

> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system
>   codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Is there a specific way i was meant to install it?

I went over to the other article to amend any paths (in environment variables), if incorrect and they all seemed to be correct but when i try to run in cmd it gives me the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: Perhaps there is still another python installation on your path, eg python2. Try go though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings + `which python` may help to locate your executable

Comment: You can alos use `conda` to create an environment with required python version, right?

Comment: Can confirm Keras works with python 3.7.2

Comment: I went to the other article suggested but i couldnt find a PYTHONHOME variable