# Django Apache error: No module named 'encodings'. Windows server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I clone repo from git. I create venv:

```
python -m venv myenv
/myenv/scripts/activate.bat
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install mod_wsgi-4.6.5+ap24vc14-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

if i run from myvenv that:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it's work!

if I run from apache, I have a error:

```
[Wed Oct 30 10:51:18.732028 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 352:tid 168] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 30 10:51:18.732028 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 352:tid 168] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug  9 2019 16:46:32
[Wed Oct 30 10:51:18.732028 2019] [core:notice] [pid 352:tid 168] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -d C:/Apache24'
[Wed Oct 30 10:51:18.732028 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 352:tid 168] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1748
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000354 (most recent call first):
[Wed Oct 30 10:51:23.677228 2019] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 352:tid 168] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

below httpd.conf:

```
LoadFile "c:/<>/python/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/envs/myproject/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"


WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/<myproject>/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/envs/myproject"
WSGIPythonPath "c:/<myproject>"


Alias /static/ "c:/<myproject>/static/"
<Directory "c:/<myproject>/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory c:/<myproject>>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
<Directory c:/<myproject>/attachments>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I  set PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH as "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts"

I looked many question, example: [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)
but this error only in apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I have done it.

I used "virtualenvwrapper" for Windows. It's really helpful.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
mkvirtualenv myenv
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install mod_wsgi-4.6.5+ap24vc14-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

It's work.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that Apache on Windows, when run as a *Service* **does not pick up the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable** which it needs for the right Python installation to be used.

If it doesn't find it, it gives a very misleading error about the `encdongs module not found`

```
    Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

To get it to work, in a Windows Terminal or CMD, run Apache as a standard executable - **not as a Service**:

```
    set PYTHONHOME=<root-of-python-or-conda-env>
    httpd  // In this case, Apache server picks up PYTHONHOME and comes up
    httpd -k start // as a service (need to be admin) - here it DOES NOT pick up PYTHONHOME and fails with the error above
```

Also note, per the mod_wsgi author, on Windows, Apache seems to ignore the *WSGIPythonHome* directive, so don't bother going down that rabbit hole.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem the OP described.  In my case I found I could get the service to work -- IF -- I configured the service to Log on as `.\Administrator` instead of `LocalService` or any other user account.  I'm still puzzling out why that would be the case and may submit it as a new question....

Answer (score 1):

Your config file seems to have no issue.
I had a similar issue, how I solved it was,

I checked my `Apache24` installation , it was 32-bit, while my python install was a 64-bit, so I had to reinstall the `Apache24 64 bit` version and put the configuration in `httpd.conf` again.

I also had to install my python in the main `C` directory instead of instead of inside the `\Users` so my base python location was `C:\Python36`, and include the `C:\Python36\` and `C:\Python36\Scripts\` inside the path of the `system variables` then create a new virtualenv and include in the Apache configuration

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the PYTHONHOME environment variable