# gcc 6.3 --> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, gcc

I am trying to install a Python package and I get this error in CentOS7:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Complete log is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/xs6zFKVg

Here is the package named Kaolin from NVIDIA: https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/kaolin

This error happens after I switch to gcc 6.3 and enter this command: `python setup.py install`

How should I fix it?

Note that, initially I had GCC 7 and I used the following commands to move onto GCC 6.3 (seems like CUDA had compatability problem with GCC 7 so I had to switch):

```
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-6
```

and

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-6 bash
```

Now I have:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
I am not sure if what I did above was the best bet or if this must have caused this new issue.
```

Comment: Did you check the other questions that come up if you search for this error, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)?

Comment: so the fix is for Windows 10. My problem arises in CentOS 7. I wonder this happened due to the potential not proper way of switching to GCC 6?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using the following commands:

```
$ conda create -p /scratch3/3d_pose/kaolin_env python=3.6 numpy cython pytorch-gpu "matplotlib<3.0.0" scikit-image shapely "trimesh>=3.0" scipy sphinx "pytest>=4.6" "pytest-cov>=2.7" tqdm Cython autopep8 flake8

$ conda activate /scratch3/3d_pose/kaolin_env

$ pip install pptk

$ python setup.py install
```

Still the `import kaolin` throws an error even from the .. of kaolin repo.