# Issue with python or powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I have a new computer and now am installing `python / opening powershell` I get this message upon opening `powershell`

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell `https://aka.ms/pscore6`

`Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

```
Current thread 0x00001370 (most recent call first):
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:90
+ ... onda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

I read this page* (below), my path is set

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
```

However I cannot find `PYTHONHOME` anywhere and I don't know how to add it.

Does anyone know how I can solve this error?

Thank you for reading :)

*[Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your "Current User, Current Host – console" Powershell profile file, **line 4**, which is located at
`C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`

Look at the **Line 4**, and check if the line is important to you. If not, remove or comment out the line and the error should be gone.

Comment: Hey there thanks for your reply.

The code message that I have put above is automatically sent out as soon as I open powershell. 

How do I remove this line

Comment: (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Did you check what you have on line 4 in your `profile.ps1`?

Comment: Ahha! You are a genius, thank you. The laptop is second hand and even with a master reset there was "anaconda" had it's hold. Profile.ps1 had this line of code '''(& "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression'''. I commented it out and I no longer had the error. Thanks a bunch!