# initfsencoding: Unable to load the file system codec after download

Tags: python-3.7

I downloaded Python 3.7, but whenever I try to run Python it shows

```py
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000069c (most recent call first):
```

Comment: what code are you trying to run and what ide do you use?

Comment: Does this solve your issue? [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: no i can't understand this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)