# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding when running Apache with mod_wsgi to deploy Flask

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I am currently attempting to deploy a Flask application using mod_wsgi and Apache. I am using Python 3.10 on a Windows 10 machine and I believe to have configured everything properly. Below is my flask_app.conf:

```
WSGIPythonHome "C:/../../venv"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX:80
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/../app/flask_app.wsgi
    <Directory C:/../flask_app>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is the relevant code added to the Apache httpd.conf file:

```
ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX:80
LoadFile <primary python3.10 dll>
LoadModule wsgi_module "venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/../venv"

Include conf/flask_app.conf
```

Strangely it appears that the server functions if I simply run the command

```
httpd.exe
```

However, it does stall on the command prompt, as if processing a continuous function.
Also, if I try to start Apache2.4 in Windows Services or use the command:

```
httpd.exe -k start
```

An error occurs on startup giving the following relevant snippet in the error.log for Apache:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

This has been a hard problem to debug and any guidance would be appreciated. Please let me know if any more information would be helpful.

Comment: do you have `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH` set in the server's environment?  (e.g. see [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings), there are many others though)

Comment: I have added both PYTHONHOME and PATH to the system variables on the server. Both are the python.exe file for the venv I am using