# Fatal Python error on Windows 10 when I try to access Python from command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, msys

I did everything from [these answers on a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings) and nothing changed. Even uninstalling Python did not improve the situation. Everything was working fine but all of a sudden it stopped working.

```
    Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\iverilog\\gtkwave\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\iverilog\\gtkwave\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python38.zip',
    'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.8',
    'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.8',
    'D:\\a\\_temp\\msys\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000029e8 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem.

Looking back, the error is fairly clear: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'` means Python is not able to find the encodings module, one of Python built-in modules. I had a look at my filesystem and found out that the encodings module is found at `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\encodings`. This meant that Python could not find that folder!

My simple solution was to add `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. On Windows you can either set it from [the Windows settings UI](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) - the permanent way - or set it temporarily from the command line, using this command: `set PYTHONPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\`.

This kind of feels like a hack since, as a basic Python module, it *should* be found automatically and yet doesn't. However, at this point, I've had no other Python-related problems so I figure it really does the trick.