# Apache2 not working with mod_wsgi: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'"

Tags: python, docker, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I run Apache2 in a Docker container and want to host my Django site using `mod_wsgi`. Anyway WSGI process fails to start and I get the error below. I tried using Python paths of the container and of a separate virtual environment, but I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
[Thu Jan 11 10:39:44.447690 2024] [wsgi:warn] [pid 316:tid 140618355098752] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=316): Unable to stat Python home /var/www/html/my-site.com.com/python3.7. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7.17-buster

WORKDIR /var/www/html/my-site.com
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/var/www/html/my-site.com/python3.7
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

COPY ./dev .
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 -y
RUN a2enmod ssl rewrite wsgi headers macro

RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
RUN source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade setuptools && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is a relevant Apache config segment:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/my-site.com/main/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess prod_$site python-home=/var/www/html/my-site.com/python3.7 python-path=/var/www/html/my-site.com/python3.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup prod_$site
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: @possum No, it doesn't. Also, I can run Python manually withing the container without issues; the error only happens from Apache.

Comment: I would recommend against running Apache within your site's container unless you have an excellent reason to do so. You also do not need a virtualenv within a container, so I'd recommend against that too.

Comment: (This setup isn't actually using the virtual environment in any case.  If `RUN source ...` isn't an error, the environment variables it sets get reset at the end of the current `RUN` directive.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Good point – it certainly isn't installing those requirements in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it. I applied the suggestions in the comments by removing virtual environment. Also, I updated `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive to use Python paths of the container.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7.17-buster

WORKDIR /var/www/html/my-site.com
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

COPY ./dev .
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 -y
RUN a2enmod ssl rewrite wsgi headers macro

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade setuptools && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`my-site.conf`

```
WSGIDaemonProcess prod_$site python-path=/var/www/html/my-site.com:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
```